# How to do Multiple joins in EF, and load datagrid, using VB

Tags: entity-framework

I'm trying to load a grid using EF objects.

```
select * from 
[session] inner join [sessionrep] on [session].ID = [sessionrep].repid
inner join [group] on [group].id = [session].groupid
where [sessionrep].repid = x
```

I created a partial class and added the properties I wanted to display in the grid in there:

```
Partial Public Class SessionRep 
Public ReadOnly Property Name() As String 
Get Return Session.Name 
End Get 
End Property 
.... 
End Class
```

I tried doing this, but it's only loading the table's Active field, the other fields are blank, although the number of rows appear right.

```
grdSessions.DataSource = db.SessionReps.Include("Session").Include("Session.Group").Include("Session.Group.Program").Where(Function(r) r.RepID = repID).ToList()
```

What am I doing wrong ? Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking how to reproduce the SQL query with LINQ to Entities? It would be easier to answer if you could show your `Session` and `SessionRep` classes and how they are related. And what is "the Active field"?

Comment: Yes, I'm just learning LINQ syntax. Having trouble writing that query using Linq. I don't want to have to use a partial class, and I think Linq to Entities is the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for partial classes.

```
Dim query = 
From s In db.Sessions 
From d In db.SessionReps 
Where s.ID = d.RepID And d.RepID = repID 
Select s 

grdSessions.DataSource = query.ToList() 
grdSessions.DataBind()
```